# Why does the Ajax function I call in my script run twice in a row when readyState is 4?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

All,

I am studying Ajax using the Head First Ajax book.  In the first chapter they give some code example which I simplified a bit.  I added a bunch of `alert` to understand what was happening.  Here is the code:

HTML + Ajax (`index.php`):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Rob's Rock 'n' Roll Memorabilia</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/default.css" />
<script>
  function createRequest() {
    try {
      request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (tryMS) {
      try {
        request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
      } catch (otherMS) {
        try {
          request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (failed) {
          request = null;
        }
      }
    }
  return request;
}

function getDetails(img){
  var title = img.title;
  alert("getDetails1");
  request = createRequest();
  alert("getDetails2");
  if (request == null) {
    alert("Unable to create request");
    return;
  }
  var url= "getDetails.php?ImageID=" + escape(title);
  alert("getDetails3");
  request.open("GET", url, true);
  alert("getDetails4");
  request.onreadystatechange = displayDetails;
  alert("getDetails5");
  request.send(null);
  alert("getDetails6");
}

function displayDetails() {
  alert("displayDetails1");
  if (request.readyState == 4) {
    alert("Request.readyState is 4");
    if (request.status == 200) {
      alert("Request.status is 200");
      detailDiv = document.getElementById("description");
      alert("displayDetails2");
      detailDiv.innerHTML = request.responseText;
      alert("displayDetails3");
    }else{
      alert("Request.status not 200");
      return;
    }
  }else{
    alert("Request.readystate not 4");
    return;
  }
}
</script>  
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="thumbnailPane">  
      <img src="images/SISL_Avatar2.JPG"
           title="SISL" id="SISL" onclick="getNextImage()" />  
      <img src="images/itemGuitar.jpg" width="301" height="105" alt="guitar" 
           title="itemGuitar" id="itemGuitar" onclick="getDetails(this)"/>
      <img src="images/itemShades.jpg" alt="sunglasses" width="301" height="88" 
           title="itemShades" id="itemShades" onclick="getDetails(this)" />
      <img src="images/itemCowbell.jpg" alt="cowbell" width="301" height="126" 
           title="itemCowbell" id="itemCowbell" onclick="getDetails(this)" />
      <img src="images/itemHat.jpg" alt="hat" width="300" height="152" 
           title="itemHat" id="itemHat" onclick="getDetails(this)" />
    </div>

    <div id="detailsPane">
      <img src="images/blank-detail.jpg" width="346" height="153" id="itemDetail" />
      <div id="description"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
</html>

<?php    
$details = array (
    'itemGuitar'    =>  "<p>Pete Townshend once played this guitar while his own axe was in the shop having bits of drumkit removed from it.</p>",
    'itemShades'    =>  "<p>Yoko Ono's sunglasses. While perhaps not valued much by Beatles fans, this pair is rumored to have been licked by John Lennon.</p>",
    'itemCowbell'   =>  "<p>Remember the famous \"more cowbell\" skit from Saturday Night Live? Well, this is the actual cowbell.</p>",
    'itemHat'       =>  "<p>Michael Jackson's hat, as worn in the \"Billie Jean\" video. Not really rock memorabilia, but it smells better than Slash's tophat.</p>"
);    
if (isset($_REQUEST['ImageID'])){echo $details[$_REQUEST['ImageID']];}
?>
```

Here is the URL that is called by Ajax (`getDetails.php`):

```
<?php

$details = array (
    'itemGuitar'    =>  "<p>Pete Townshend once played this guitar while his own axe was in the shop having bits of drumkit removed from it.</p>",
    'itemShades'    =>  "<p>Yoko Ono's sunglasses. While perhaps not valued much by Beatles fans, this pair is rumored to have been licked by John Lennon.</p>",
    'itemCowbell'   =>  "<p>Remember the famous \"more cowbell\" skit from Saturday Night Live? Well, this is the actual cowbell.</p>",
    'itemHat'       =>  "<p>Michael Jackson's hat, as worn in the \"Billie Jean\" video. Not really rock memorabilia, but it smells better than Slash's tophat.</p>"
);
echo $details[$_REQUEST['ImageID']];
?>
```

**The question: Why does the function `displayDetails` run twice at readystate 4?**

When I run the above, the code seems to run through the `displayDetails()` function twice.  I first get the `displayDetails1` alert signaling I've entered the function.  I then get the alerts related to the `readyState` not being 4, then not being 4 again, then being 4 (`Request.readyState is 4`).  Then the status alert tells me the status is 200.  Up to now, nothing unexpected.

**After that I get something weird.**  I get the `displayDetails2` alert, then the page is modified according to the function and I get the `displayDetails3` alert.  I then expect to exit the function.  Instead I get again the `displayDetails1`, `Request.readyState is 4` (**a second time!**), `Request.status is 200`, `displayDetails2`, and `displayDetails3` alerts, as if the entire function had run a second time.  Why is that?

PS:
1) After the 2nd round, I then get the `getDetails6` alert I expect.
2) The page functions as it should - from a user's standpoint there's nothing unusual if the alerts are disabled.
3) I am developing locally on WampServer, on a WinXP machine (I know...).
4) If I add:

```
function alert(msg) {
  console.log(msg);
}
```

to my script the log only registers one `readyState is 4`...

**RESOLUTION**

I have done 3 tests:
1 - with the alerts only, I get two `readyState is 4` alerts.
2 - if I log the alerts, the log only shows one `readyState is 4` alert.
3 - if I both log and display the alert pop-ups (using [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14716439/javascript-function-to-both-log-and-show-pop-up-alerts)), I get two `readyState is 4` alerts (and the log shows that).

My take on this is that it is the alerts themselves that cause a script execution delay and cause the function to effectively run twice.

Comment: I didn't study this too much because I think your issue is a non-issue. What you are doing when this line runs _request.onreadystatechange = displayDetails_ is initiating an on-event method. The "readystate" changes (I think) 4 times when initiating an async call. And each time it changes it calls that function. It is only when the readystate returns a 4 that the "if" statement runs. So what you need to look at more is the readystate process and the onEvent method relationship

Comment: Try using the console and breakpoints rather than alerts. You will get much more information to help debug.

Comment: Here are the different readyState stages 
0 = uninitialized; 1 = loading; 2 = loaded; 3 = interactive; 4 = complete

Comment: @Jimmy - Why does the function run twice once readyState is 4?

Comment: In addition to the behavior you explicitly ask about, it's also strange that you don't get your `getDetails6` until after the request has completed; that implies that your request is synchronous, but `request.open("GET", url, true)` should create an asynchronous one.

Comment: I think you need to take out your "else{returns;}" This could be your problem

Comment: @Jimmmy - no, removing the `returns` doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The javascript `alert` is blocking your UI thread, probably long enough for your browser to finish loading the AJAX request.  Since you don't check the `request.readyState` until after the alert, it can be updated by the browser before you check it.

Try modifying your event handler:

```
function displayDetails() {
  var rs = request.readyState;
  alert("displayDetails1");
  if (rs == 4) {
    alert("Request.readyState is 4");
    //rest of code...
```

You will see just one alert of "Request.readyState is 4"

Comment: That was the problem.  When I log the alerts I get only one `readyState is 4` whereas if I both log the alerts and show the pop-ups I get two.

Answer (score 5):

The `onreadystatechange` event isn't only triggered after the request has completed. There are 5 states defined for the XMLHttpRequest:

- 0 Uninitialized
  The initial value.
- 1 Open
  The open() method has been successfully called.
- 2 Sent
  The UA successfully completed the request, but no data has yet been received.
- 3 Receiving
  Immediately before receiving the message body (if any). All HTTP headers have been received.
- 4 Loaded

Normally when developing AJAX applications you will be only interested the state 4 - loaded, as it the means the request has finished, but there are other states that you can observe.

So you don't have to worry about that second call to you event handler. **This is normal behaviour**. It just means the request has changed its inner state during its work.

If you are interested in that states I would advice you to log all states to the javascript console to see what is happening. I would also give you the tipp test this when loading large data. It is likely that you'll see multiple 3 - recieving - states.

---

Update, maybe I understand your question wrong (but not your code ;) .. You told in comments that you see two times ready state 4. I've tested this at home and the 100ths of alerts looked weird to me.

I then added the following function to your javascript section:

```
function alert(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
}
```

This redirects all alerts to the javascript debug console. I got the following output:

[image]

I see only one time ready state 4. Seems that you selfish gone wired because of so much alert() ;)

---

Update2: As I mentioned in the comments and @thanks Jeff-Meadows who also pointed this out: Note that the `alert()` function will block the javascript thread unless you press the ok button. As asynchronous XHR requests will being handled by a separate browser thread, the XHR will continue loading while javascript blocks on the alert message. You see that this can / will unwanted side effects and makes alert() less worth for debugging purposes.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding you -- or maybe I'm misunderstanding the OP -- but it sounds like you've only described the behavior that the OP already understood. The OP's question is -- if I may paraphrase -- "how come my handler is called twice with state == 4"?

Comment: Hmmm I've read the question again. I can't find a hint for two times state 4

Comment: @ruakh the OP said "I then get the alerts related to the readyState not being 4, then not being 4 again, then being 4." which is referring to the "else" alert. This looks like normal behavior

Comment: I'll test the code locally. This often helps to understand problems. @Jimmmy Give me two minutes.. will drop a comment again

Comment: OK, d'oh! the bold "After that I get something weird"

Comment: Yes this can be possible. It means that the data is retrieved in two blocks. I have tested from localhost. Therefore just a single block. So, is the question answered?

Comment: Well, I definitely get two readyState=4.  I don't understand the last sentence of your edited response.  Also, I'm willing to try adding your console log function to my code but I don't know how to retrieve the console...?

Comment: Updated sentence. You should definitely use the console attempt.. The alert-debug is CRAP.

Comment: OK, when I use the console I only see one `readyState` is 4.  But that doesn't explain why I see two `alerts` and as it stands I have no reason to believe that the console gives me more accurate info than the alerts....

Comment: Oh, btw thank you for the console tip.  And I'm still confused by what you mean when you say "selfish gone wired"...

Comment: I'm not natural english speaker. I just meant: That much alerts makes debugging very hard ( for humans ).. And of course the alerts are not that good for the debugging as the console. Note that alert will halt the javascript code unless you press ok. This can have **major** side effects