# Javascript function to both log and show pop-up alerts?

Tags: javascript, ajax

All,

I was shown this function to log alerts:

```
function alert(msg) {
  console.log(msg);
}
```

How would I modify it to both log the alerts **and** show the usual pop up?

(The reason I want to do that is that I want to test the effect the pop-ups have on delaying the execution of my JS script - so I will run the script twice, with and without pop ups, and compare the logs.)

Comment: The `alert()` function definitely pauses JavaScript execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call it something else:

```
function shout(msg) {
  alert(msg);
  console.log(msg);
}
```

Comment: Doh...  I should have thought of it.

Answer (score 1):

```
function _alert(msg)
{
 alert(msg);
 console.log(msg);
}
```